# how to render jsonresponse to template in django 1.9

Tags: json, django, leaflet, geojson, geodjango

I want to render geojson data on map and want to show pop up when user clicks on marker. Below is the code in views.py

```
def extract_raster_points(request):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="geodjango",host='localhost',user='postgres',          password='postgres', port=5433)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    res=dict_cur.execute("""SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM ( SELECT      'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry ,row_to_json((SELECT l FROM (SELECT id, species,rastvalues) As l )) As properties FROM pft_account As lg   ) As f )  As fc;""")

    points=dict_cur.fetchone()
    #datapot = json.loads(str(points))
    datapot = json.loads(json.dumps(points))
    datapotg=datapot[0]
    print(datapotg)
    return JsonResponse(datapotg,safe=False)
```

models.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
    #spid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    species=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    x=models.FloatField()
    y=models.FloatField()

    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    first_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    rastvalues=models.IntegerField()
    objects=models.GeoManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.species, self.geom.x, self.geom.y, self.rastvalues)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^potpft.data/$', extract_raster_points, name='extract_raster_points'),
    url(r'^data.data/$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=Account), name='datapotg'),
```

pot_pft.html(Javascript code)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function main_map_init (map, options) {
             var promise  = $.getJSON('{% url "datapotg" %}');
            // Download GeoJSON via Ajax
            promise.then(function(data) {
            var allbusinesses = L.geoJson(data);
            var cafes = L.geoJson(data, {
            filter: function(feature) {
                return feature.properties.rastvalues == "3";
                },
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {

                }).on('mouseover', function() {
                    this.bindPopup(feature.properties.model["rastvalues"]).openPopup();
                });
            }
        });

             var others = L.geoJson(data, {
            filter: function(feature) {
                return feature.properties.rastvalues != "3";
            },
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                }).on('mouseover', function() {
                    this.bindPopup(feature.properties.model["rastvalues"]).openPopup();
                });
            }
        });
         map.fitBounds(allbusinesses.getBounds(), {
            padding: [50, 50]
        });
        cafes.addTo(map)
        others.addTo(map)

        });
        }
    </script>
```

How can I render jsonresponse to template i.e(pft_pot.html)?

Comment: What's your question? What's wrong with this code? What happens when you try it? (And if you want to call the `extract_raster_methods` endpoint from your JS, shouldn't you use that URL, not the "datapotg" one?)

Comment: For the statement return render(request, 'pot_pft.html', datapotg) in views.py , the geojson points are getting displayed on map but properties of the geojson data i.e(species, rastvalues) are not showing up because of invalid json. But if I use return JsonResponse(datapotg,safe=False) the geojson is valid but how to render it on map?(it dispalys geojson data in browser)

Comment: I don't understand in the slightest. You have one view that presumably renders pot_pft.html, and that HTML file contains an Ajax request to request the JSON. But that Ajax request surely needs to actually point to the view that returns JSON, no?

Comment: My question is If I use  return JsonResponse(datapotg,safe=False). How can I render it on map? What necessary changes should I make in Javascript and urls.py?